# iPad - how to secure content in UItextview?

Tags: iphone

I'm developing my app in iPad. I'm designing a login page. In that I need to secure the content in textview (password). Please help me. I know how to do it for textfield, but I need that in `UITextview`.

Answer (score 10):

[This reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html) will help you.

Just add this to your code

```
textView.secureTextEntry = YES;
```

Comment: UITextView doesn't have ".secureTextEntry" feature - only UITextField has this.